# foreach as from multiple arrays in single query

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have:

```
foreach($Opts['img'] as $img)
{
}
```

I want to add:

```
foreach($Opts['lnk'] as $lnk)
```

Which I initially read, to do so just put them as follows:

```
foreach($Opts['img'] as $img)
{
    foreach($Opts['lnk'] as $lnk)
    {
    }
}
```

However this duplicates all of the results so I end up with 9 images instead of 3.

Is there a way of getting the info from both array's in the same query? I want to end up with $img showing the image address and $lnk showing the link address.

Comment: no. foreach loops on a single array only. if you want to loop on two arrays in parallel, you'll have to merge the arrays into a single one and loop that, or have some kind of key-mapping system to relate the two arrays' entries to each other.

Comment: Are the keys the same in each array?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes they are

Comment: whats your array look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For identical keys, just use the key in the `foreach`:

```
foreach($Opts['img'] as $key => $img)
{
    $lnk = $Opts['lnk'][$key];

    echo "$img and $lnk";
}
```